Are GitHub Actions open source?
So far from what i have seen:
all Actions are using the MIT LICENSE, which allows to change and spread the code when continueing to use that licesene.
GitHub Actions also have to be kept on a public Git Repository which enables forking, thus enabling to changing the code and making an own version of the action
Is there some exceptions? Im not familiar with all the open source cases and licenses. I suppose there are private actions at enterprise level but of course their code is not published, so "Open Source" usually.
tried to find a statement that explicitly states that your action is open source in GitHub docs like here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/sharing-automations/creating-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace
Might this so obvious that it doesn't need an explanation

"all Actions are using the MIT LICENSE" — Seems like you've answered your question just with that.

its from what i have seen, but i cant see everything obviously

As with any other piece of software whose source code is publicly available, it's only Open Source if the source code is under an Open Source license. While GitHub tries to encourage putting an Open Source license on any of the source code hosted at GitHub (see https://choosealicense.com/), there is no strict need to do so, and GitHub action's source code, just like any source code, might be unlicensed (e.g. not have a license at all) or be put under a non-Open-Source-license.
TL;DR there is no general answer, it depends on the exact GitHub action.
